# How to retrieve culture info of excel with open XML?

Tags: .net, excel, openxml, cultureinfo, culture

Number values in my excel files are stored with "." decimal seperator. I wonder, excel always use "." as decimal seperator? If not, then how can I retrive culture info of excel file to format decimal values correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: did you found how to retrieve Excel file CultureInfo?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and checked all XML files of a spreadsheet for language codes.

I didn't find any language codes, so I made the assumption that the number format is in englisch (en-US).

That's my code to read the column and parse it back (ToString) to my current culture.

```
    private string GetCellValue(Cell cell, SharedStringTable stringTable)
    {
        string value = string.Empty;

        if ((cell.DataType != null) && (cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))
        {
            int stringId = int.Parse(cell.CellValue.Text);
            value = stringTable.ChildElements[stringId].InnerText;
        }
        else if (cell.CellValue != null)
        {
            value = cell.CellValue.Text;

            if (decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out var number))
            {
                value = number.ToString();
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
```

You can also check for `Number` type of the `cell.DataType` property.